# Centre-aligning with CSS - since it's replaced <CENTER>, could it, at least, work properly?

Tags: css, inline, centering

I have a simple request which CSS appears unable to deliver...

I'd like 3 DIVs side-by-side - the first and third DIVs contain a single image - the second DIV contains a line of text, an image, another line of text.

They should appear this

```
IMAGE1  TEXT1  IMAGE2
        IMAGE2
        TEXT2
```

With - and this is the bit I cannot make work - TEXT1, IMAGE2 and TEXT2 centered within the width of the 2nd DIV - something like this

```
   MY TEXT
MY WIDER IMAGE
     TEXT
```

The CENTER tag would have done this in seconds, but CSS cannot apparently do something as simple as that!?!?

p.s. in reply to a request for code - something like this for starters

```
<DIV>
  <IMG src=image1.jpg>
</DIV>
<DIV>
  <p>text 1</p>
  <IMG src=image2.jpg>
  <p>text 2</p>
</DIV>
<DIV>
  <IMG src=image3.jpg>
</DIV>
```

The basic CSS would be

```
.DIV {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
```

All I need is the magic to make that centre DIV align it's contents centrally in the way the CENTER tag would have achieved in milliseconds...

and I've tried a variety of things including inline-block, margin: auto etc. -

Comment: Can you show your css and html?

Comment: agreed - we need to see the code you're having trouble with before we can really help. What techniques you have actually tried to get them to center?

Comment: I've tried so many different permutations of display, float, text-align, margin: auto that I couldn't show them all in a month.

I'm open to any solution which achieves the end result!!

Comment: re your edit and the basic CSS you gave us: `float:left;` is always going to be problematic when trying to center things. Also using `float:left` renders the `display:inline` property irrelevant.

Comment: This is one of those classic situations where good-old tables and the center tag offered a proper solution and where CSS struggles (esp as this is just part of a page layout!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

1. `float` your `div`s
2. use `text-align:center` for the text
3. wrap your images and give them `margin:1em auto`

**HTML**

```
<DIV>
    <p><IMG src=image1.jpg></p>
</DIV>
<DIV>
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p><IMG src=image2.jpg></p>
    <p>text 2</p>
</DIV>
<DIV>
    <p><IMG src=image3.jpg></p>
</DIV>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
}

div p{
    text-align:center;
}

div p img{
    width:20px;
    margin:1em auto;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PvgSr/

Comment: All 3 answers helped me along the way - this is just the most thorough and so it gets the tick I think

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should place `<br>` after your image and first text in `DIV2`. Then you should apply `text-align: center` to `DIV2`. These are the only things I can suggest you without seeing the code.

**EDIT:**

Applied `text-align: center` to the inner paragraph and centered the image separately, please see http://jsfiddle.net/Lapple/UAm5p/1/

Comment: text-align simply doesn't work - I've tried it in every possible combination - all it will do is align text within it's own container, not within other objects in a container

Comment: without display: inline, the divs will take-up the full page width and not sit alongside each other???

Comment: OK - I tried removing the display and it made no difference BUT if I take my code out of it's page layout and put it into a file on it's own, that does work - so clearly I'm inheriting something from the container (or it's container and so on)

Comment: I managed to solve this with a mixture of what everyone posted and some kicking of the surrounding code (what gets inheritted and what doesn't is an eternal mystery to me!)

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Without seeing your code it's difficult to answer but</s> Here is [a very simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/9CSbx/1/) (jsfiddle) of basically what you have described.

Comment: OK - I can see what that's trying to do - my problem probably stems from the wider page's layout (the container in which this code is displayed is display:inline for a variety of reasons - I need to fiddle with that to stop it passing it's effects into my code - I'll tinker but it's nice to see it can work, in theory :)

Comment: When something is `inline` it doesn't really have a width, it goes with the flow. You can't centre something if it doesn't have any bounds to which it should be centred.